# Close fullscreen-mode conditionally in React when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, youtube-api

In my React App I have video-frame from youtube/vimeo and need to close youtube fullscreenmode (if it is enabled) to show user some messages, when component's state changes (f.e. I generate question to user every 5 minutes and want to show pop-up).
It seems that I can't handle state/redux-store changes in case youtubeframe is in fullscreen.

And as I know I can't show popup over youtube frame in fullscreen, so the only way is to exit fullscreen mode when I want to show popup, but I don't know how I can do it.

JS-code for detecting fullscreen mode and closing fullscreen mode I have, but I can't run it in fullscreen.